# Convert one dimensional arrays in a pandas dataframe to numbers

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, scalar

Values of a pandas dataframe contain one dimensional arrays and i would like to convert into floats
without the "[]" . Tried this but does not work . How can [0.5142399408894116] be converted to 0.5142399408894116

```
dfPredictions = pd.DataFrame(data = dff, dtype='float')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index operator [] on the array:

```
[0.5142399408894116][0]
    = 0.5142399408894116
```

If you need to apply this to a dataframe row, use the explode method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [[0.5142399408894116], [0.1423994088941165], [0.4239940889411651]]})

df
    col
0   [0.5142399408894116]
1   [0.1423994088941165]
2   [0.4239940889411651]

df.explode('col')

    col
0   0.51424
1   0.142399
2   0.423994
```

Comment: Thanks , but how do i apply this to all values of the dataframe?

Comment: That's another question.